# Curve to mesh option is disabled

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

I am using 2.80 blender version due to system requirement. I want to convert bazier curve into mesh. [image]I applied mirror modifier on curve. When I tried to apply it on object it gives me message first convert curve into mesh.I am trying to convert it in object mode > Object > convert to > mesh from curve /meta/ surf/ text but both options are disabled or grayed out due to which i can not apply it. I am attaching a screenshot. Please do the needful.

Comment: is your object selected? Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 2):

The object is active (yellow origin visible):

[image]

But not selected (yellow or orange outlines visible):

[image]

Comment: in edit mode, when i select curve it is visible but to convert into mesh i need to go object mode as per the tutorials hence I go to object mode and that selection disappears. As I uploaded screenshot it is not selected as here shown. I don't know any other method of selection.

Comment: If you test to press A in object mode, no selection?

Comment: I have not converted curve, into mesh and I can select curve. In my screenshot at collection stack, the selection of curve is visible. but objects is not in yellow but the curves are

Comment: The object is not selected in the collection here. Click on it from the collection (should be yellow on blue).

Comment: let me tell you the process i did so that you will come to know what exactly the problem is. I created bezier curve and apply mirror modifier to it  for z axis. I reshape it so that I will get the above result. now bazier curve, modifier is visible in the stack under one collection bazier curve.To make mesh visible from curve , under CONTEXT OBBJECT DATA menu I increase depth value which transformed curve into visible object but it is not yet mesh.to convert it into mesh.

Comment: if I am selecting the curve, as soon as I go to object mode the selection is disappearing

Comment: The selection should not disappear in the process you're describing here. Your Blender version seems to be 2.80. Would you mind upgrading it to 2.83 or 2.90?

Comment: in 2.80 I can atleast work with few blinking issue. but in 2.90 or even higher than 2.80 version I can not even see menu option properly. all menus become transperant and can not read or see polygon selection etc, I searched it require opengl 3.3 or higher. I have 3.3  but still there is an issue

Comment: I'll try to see if I can get the exact same version as yours and test it. Will let you know

Comment: OK, I've installed 2.80.75 and tested it. All is fine here and I've not the same issue as you described. Could be due to your computer. Though, what is happening when you click in the outliner to select the curve?

Comment: Sir, as you can see in my screenshot i made a model in different parts. all parts are made by polygon or box modeling. only this part I made with bezier as I am new to blender and learning it. All other parts are properly highlighting after selection and all options are available for them but only this part is not showing those option. There is no comp issue but technique issue.I can not select that shape in object mode. and without object mode i can not convert it into mesh. I agree it should be selected but how can I select that part is my question.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbSoSGZ3eu4 Please see this link for detailed explinition of my question